# Make Trashcan Carla friendly again using commands

Tags: fallout-4

Is there a way to make Trashcan Carla friendly again after you rob her? I tried things like `disable` and `markfordelete` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't work because it's actually a hidden quest that you "completed".

**Before you do any of this, do a full save**, not a quick save. Since this is a "vanilla" quest (part of the base game), futzing around with it can sometimes have unintended bad consequences.

The quest id we're targetting is "caravanbase". You can see the stages by running the command `ShowQuestStages caravanbase`. (`sqs` is shorthand for ShowQuestStages if you find yourself doing this a lot.) The quest can be reset entirely using the `resetquest caravanbase` command.

So:

```
sqs caravanbase
resetquest caravanbase
```

My current playthrough is in survival so I can't verify, but the above is from my notes from a previous playthrough when I did the same thing and regretted it.

Some googling brought up [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/6ln39q/how_do_you_reset_trashcan_carla/) which has some additional commands if the above doesn't work.

However I've followed this set of commands in several playthroughs and they've always worked a charm. I can't say how mods might affect this, though -- I don't play with mods.

Comment: Although this (and some other commands from the reddit thread) solve the "robbery" issue, now I can't see any dialog option. She just says "Hay, want to trade?" (something along those lines) and sits there. Since this might be because of mods etc, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh -- that's odd. Yeah I've never played modded F4, so that's possibly it. Does she trade with you, at least?

Comment: Nope, she simple says her lines and nothing happens. No dialog/trade prompt. I thought it might have been the XDI mod but disabling didn't fix it. Oh well, no big deal.